# cURL status bar not displaying

Tags: curl

I have done something in a bash script and my cURL command is no longer showing the status bar. I need to save the HTTP response code to a variable, $status:

I have:

```
status=$(curl -s -S -o curl.tmp -w %{http_code} --progress-bar -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -T "$FILE_TO_UPLOAD" "$FILE_ON_REMOTE_SERVER" )
status=$(($status + 0)) # force integer

if [[ $status > 400 ]]; then
   # an error occurred; do something
fi
```

Why isn't the progress bar displaying?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-s` option for "silent mode" will prevent curl from showing the progress bar:

From the curl man page:

> `-s`, `--silent`
>
> > Silent or quiet mode. **Don't show progress meter** or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for, potentially even to the
> >                   terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.
> >
> > Use `-S`, `--show-error` in addition to this option to disable progress meter but still show error messages.
> >
> > See also `-v`, `--verbose` and `--stderr`.